# Is it possible to set new field value when analyzing document being indexed in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

For example:

1. when indexing one document into elasticsearch;
2. i want to analyze a field named `description` in the document by `uax_url_email` tokenizer/analyzer;
3. if `description` does have any url, put the url into another field named `urls` array;
4. finish index this document;

Now i can check whether field `urls` is empty to know whether `description` has any url.

Is this possible? Or does analyzer only contributes to the inverted index, not other fields?

Comment: copy_to feature could help you
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html

Comment: @LeBigCat Thanks, but `It is the field value which is copied, not the terms (which result from the analysis process)`, and i what to copy the extracted url but not the raw `description` field.

Comment: @puppylpg you description field have one URL or multipul URL?

Comment: Have you looked into ingestion pipelines ?

Comment: @SagarPatel `description` is a block of text, may has one or multiple url and any other text.

Comment: @Paulo yeah, I'm looking into ingestion, seems that it's a resonable way to process data before indexing. Still looking. Thanks~

Comment: @puppylpg You can try out grok processor from ingest pipeline but it will give only first occurns of url that is my understanding. But you can explore it.

Comment: @SagarPatel yeah, grok is suitable if it can match multiple times... It does match only once and i still can't find how to repeat. Any suggestions?

Comment: @puppylpg i am also not sure as i know it return only first one.

Comment: @puppylpg Please check below my answer. I hope it will help you !!!

Comment: @SagarPatel Thanks so much, that really helps me! Sorry for late response, blocked by another problem yesterday :D

Comment: @puppylpg no worries !! I am gald that my answer help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ingest Pipeline Script processor with painless script. I hope this will help you.

```json
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate?verbose
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "description": "Extract 'tags' from 'env' field",
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            
            def m = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])/.matcher(ctx["content"]);
            ArrayList urls = new ArrayList();
            while(m.find())
            {
              urls.add(m.group());
            }
            ctx['urls'] = urls;
          """,
          "params": {
            "delimiter": "-",
            "position": 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "content": "My name is Sagar patel and i visit https://apple.com and https://google.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Above Pipeline will generate result like below:

```json
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "processor_results": [
        {
          "processor_type": "script",
          "status": "success",
          "description": "Extract 'tags' from 'env' field",
          "doc": {
            "_index": "_index",
            "_id": "_id",
            "_source": {
              "urls": [
                "https://apple.com",
                "https://google.com"
              ],
              "content": "My name is Sagar patel and i visit https://apple.com and https://google.com"
            },
            "_ingest": {
              "pipeline": "_simulate_pipeline",
              "timestamp": "2022-07-13T12:45:00.3655307Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```